# ActionScript 3 Save File Error (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash

I am a student in school making a low scale virtual world for a project. I am following the book "Flash Multiplayer Virtual Worlds" by Makzan. In the book, I am told to make an ActionScript 3 Document Class.

However, when I try saving this class, I receive this message and can not save it.

[image]

I am running MacOS Sierra. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not actually related to Flash or AS3. MacOS is like Unix or Linux, it has a set of access rights to each filesystem object, these right define what kind of access you can have. The filename "/Ch03_01.as" means you are trying to save your file to filesystem root, where the regular user should not have write access by any means. Save your project files to the folder your current user has full access (most probably to your user home folder).

Comment: Put `.as` file in same place as FLA file.